# Get last record in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database as such

```
  Update       Record_ID   Index    Location
    1          1             23       China
    1          1             24       Beijing
    1          1             45       Norway
    1          1             23       China
    2          1             423      Somne
    2          1             24       Beijing
    2          1             243      Nevela
    3          1             334      DEro
    3          1             555      Mood
```

I have tried other examples on this site which can't solve my situation yet so please don't be fast to tag this as a duplicate.

**In this scenario i have only 1 record 1 but they could be thousands.**

So i need to get the last record of Updates for all unique records. So in this case i should have something like this returned for record 1:

```
 3          1             334      DEro
 3          1             555      Mood
```

and if there is record 2 etc they will be included here as well.

I tried using "LIMIT" but my query returned only 1 row in this case.

```
3          1             555      Mood
```

**PS: There is an autogenerated PK column for this table which i didnt include.**

**[Online Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e7fb/1)**.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you want? Do you want to select the last 2 rows? Is that it?

Comment: Not the last two rows. The last list of records inserted per Update. 2 rows was an example of what it couldve returned in that scenario

Comment: Ahhh I see, so your Unique Field is the index field right?

Comment: Hmmm no actually index is just another data. I have a unique column which is autogenerated but not included. I feel like i can do this without that column

Comment: For example DISTINCT Update_ID will give me unique 1-many relationship.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without the unique record, because you said you want the latest update of all unique records, which means you have to include the unique record for the records to show right. I think I understand what you mean. Can you include the unique record so I could fiddle around the SQL statement I have in mind? :) I may be wrong, but what I have in mind right now definitely needs the unique record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT * FROM table t1 
JOIN (SELECT Record_ID  ,MAX(Updates)as maxupdate FROM table GROUP BY Record_ID)x 
ON t1.Record_ID = x.Record_ID  AND t1.Updates=x.maxupdate
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfcdb/1)

It also works for multiple Record_id

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE `Update` = (SELECT TOP 1 `Update` FROM Table_Name ORDER BY ID DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is what I came up with... It works on SQLFiddle :) I got the results you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM s 
WHERE updates=(SELECT MAX(updates) as Latest_Update
               FROM s
               GROUP BY record_id)
```

Comment: What if he has more than 1 record_id?

Comment: Sorry it didnt work. Mihai gave the solution. Thanks for trying.